# SOLR Is it normal 2 minutes to index 50K items?

Tags: solr

> Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 53011 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 2m 30s)

I'm using the default configuration and my records are very simple, just title | year| author

Comment: it depends on hardware as well. can you please share nodes configuration?

Comment: this is using DIH right? show us the dih config

Comment: what's DIH?????

Comment: it's Data Import Handler. most likely you have data-config.xml somewhere in Solr distribution that is running indexing, we need it

Comment: @Francesco will you provide any needed info?